# Joomla Website not working

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have a site call Ptbnews24 http://www.ptbnews24.com. This site has been created using Joomla 2.5 and I have a problem when I click category or menu link, it shows the error `No input file specified.` I've no idea how to get around this, can someone please provide a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a basic summary, make sure you have `Apache mod_rewrite = Yes`, and `Search Engine Friendly URLs = Yes`. Then in the **.htaccess** file you must have the following:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
```

If you already hae this, check out the solution somebody provided on the [Joomlart Forum](http://www.joomlart.com/forums/showthread.php?17234-Getting-SEO-to-work-on-GoDaddy-Shared-Accounts).

Note: To find out if **Apache mod_rewrite** is set to **"yes"**, you will need to contact your host. However it most likely will be by default.

Comment: Note you can see if mod_rewrite is being loaded (but not whether it's set to yes) in Site->System Information->PHP information. Then on that page under Configuration->apache2handler look to see whether mod_rewrite is under the modules being loaded. If its being loaded it almost certainly being set to yes